# log4net - logging from mutliple machines to a centralized file

Tags: logging, log4net

We have a relay server and behind it there are multiple servers. I am thinking of using log4net and to log the data from those servers in a central repository (relay) . I would like to use rolling FileAppender but I see there will be issues with locking as there are multiple machines involved.  Can I use remoteAppender for this and the sink will be on relay server or is there any other better alternative.

I tried to google related to this but didn't find a proper example on RemoteAppender

Please advise.

Thanks,
sveerap

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use ado.net appender it this situation. I works fine with multiple machines, and logs can be easily viewed and filtered.

Comment: I have to make sure the logging time would be as minimal as possible . As database logging would consume some time, thought of logging to flat files.

Answer (score 1):

I thought to suggest UDPAppender, without guarantee that all of your messages gets logged.

I will implement a TCP client which listens for incoming log information, running in a central machine. It will receive the log messages from other machines and will log through rolling file appender.

I have used Telnet Appender.

You can also configure RemotingAppender for that purpose. See this,

http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F14274%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the response. If we compare this with logging into database option, will this option is better in speed?.